# The documentation of Mathalfa and tx \mathbb{1}

Tags: documentation, txfonts, mathalfa

I've not been able to produce a `\mathbb{1}` with `\usepackage[bb=tx]{mathalfa}`. I haven't been able to produce anything of that matter (no blackboard bold symbols of the ones I've tried - just some random ones).

I've then tried `\usepackage{txfonts}`, however this doesn't have `\mathbb{1}` or `\varmathbb{1}`. The reason I believe there should be a blackboard bold 1 is the following (part of the mathalfa-package documentation):
[image: Screenshot taken from the notes-section of mathalfa documentation.]
I'm not familiar enough to check if the documentation is wrong, and I'm hopeful that it isn't.

For reference I've used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts} % Interchanging this with mathalfa
\usepackage[bb=tx]{mathalfa} % Interchanging this with txfonts

\begin{document}
$\varmathbb{R1}\mathbb{R1}$
\end{document}
```